# HP ProBook 4540 overheating issue

Tags: kde, hp, overheating

I am dual booting with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. In Windows there is no heating issue. But in Ubuntu it is heating too much. I am using KDE.

Comment: HP ProBook 4540 apparently came in two flavors, one with Intel Graphics and the other with AMD. Which one is yours?

Comment: Mine one is Intel Graphics

Comment: Run `sudo tlp stat` and see whether the CPU or storage temperatures are high

Comment: Also report what drivers are being used in **Additional Drivers**

Comment: I do not use any additional driver. CPU temperature is 48 C.

Comment: @TanjeelKhan Since CPU temperature is normal, are you sure you are don't have AMD graphics? Please add the screenshot of **Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers** to your question.

Comment: How it's normal? 35-40 should be normal.